# returning a palindrome at an index - Python

Tags: python-3.x

```
def palindrome(s,index):

    if s.islower() and s.isalpha():
        num=1
        if s[index-num]==s[index+num]:
            num+=1
            return s[index-num:index+(num+1)]
        return s[index]

    return ''
```

i have to Return the longest odd-length palindrome in the string that is centered at the specified index , My Palindrome function does not work for example if i do >>>palindrome('noonoon',3) i get 'oonoo' rather than 'noonoon'

Comment: Hint: you're not looping over anything. You just have one if, so your code either returns nothing, one letter, or 5 letters.

Comment: @matanso thanks for the hint but i cant figure out a way for looping

Comment: (`I'm supposed to return a palindrome at a given index` there's `s[index:index+1]`: ) Please specify what palindrome to return: longest starting at index? Longest centred at index? Something else?

Comment: Do _not_ comment comments asking for additional information or clarification: edit your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def palindrome(s,index):
    output=s[index]
    for before,after in zip(s[:index][::-1],s[index+1:]):
        if before==after:
            output=before+output+after
        else: break
    if output==s[index]: return ''
    else: return output


>>> palindrome('youtubecat',3)
'utu'
```

The `for` loop is looping outward from `s[index]`. So `before` is looping through `'uoy'` (`you` reversed, hence the `[::-1]` reverse splice)     and `after` is looping through `'ube'`. While `before` and `after` are the same, it's being appended to `s[index]`. As soon as they aren't the same, it returns the output. If a palindrome cannot be made from the `index` location, then an empy string is returned.

Just so it's clear,  `after` isn't looping through `'ubecat'` because when you `zip` both objects have to be the same length, which is why it's truncated to `'ube'`.

```
>>> palindrome('racecar',3)
'racecar'
```

If case isn't an issue (ie `'A'='a'`) then use the `lower()` method in the `if` statement:

`if before.lower()==after.lower()`

If you want an alternate way to do it:

```
def palindrome(s,index):
    mirror=min([len(s[:index]),len(s[index+1:])])
    s=s[index-mirror:index]+s[index:index+mirror+1]
    while s:
        if len(s)==1: return ''
        if s==s[::-1]: return s # check if it's a palindrome
        else:                   # if not, remove the first and last char
            s=s[1:-1]
```

Comment: yes for the noonoon example it does however if i do like palindrome('youtubecat',3) it gives me 'youtuoy' instead of utu

Comment: i guess i was not clear, i have to  Return the longest odd-length palindrome in the string that is centered at the specified index.

Comment: @CAVS, updated the response. Didn't realize that's what you were looking to do.

Comment: is there another way

Comment: Sure, but that depends what you are looking for? Does this not work for some reason?

Comment: @CAVS, I posted a new one that does not use `zip` and uses a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to loop through the string:

```
def palindrome(s,index):

    if s.islower() and s.isalpha():
        num=0
        while index > num and index + num + 1 < len(s) and s[index-num-1]==s[index+num+1]:
            num+=1
        return s[index - num : index + num + 1]
    return ''
```

Comment: i get 'ono' now